# Visual Studio 'add connection' window missing 'Database file name' option

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, database-connection

when trying to add a database connection to the server explorer in Visual Studio, the window looks like the first image I loaded(img1) whereas it should look like the second one(img2). Why is that? How am I supposed to connect to the database this way?[img1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp0Jd.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hp0Jd.png), [image: img2]

Thanks in advance

Restarting and reinstalling Visual Studio, checking regedit for disabled features ...

Comment: With SQL server you can have a locale database which is a mdf filename or the mdf file can be attached to a server.  If mdf file is attached to the server than you cannot connect as a local db because the server owns the mdf file.  The first image is connecting to a attached database, while second is attaching to a local db.  Can you connect to db using SQL Server Management Studio?

Comment: Don't use `AttachDbFilename` options or equivalent. Just open SSMS and attach the database files properly.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I have an sqLite file inside my project.  When I googled for how to connect to my database in visual studio, all the instructions show the window which opens after clicking 'Connect to database' inb server explorer as it is in the second image. But when I choose 'sqLite Provider' under data sources, there is no browse option and only an option for entering the connection string.

Comment: Install VS.Data.Sqlite extension and connect

Comment: @Charlieface: Hi, would SSMS work with a sqLite db?

Comment: No it wouldn't. But your screenshot indicates you are using SQL Server not SQLite. For SQLite I think you just put it into the connection string. https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlite/

Comment: Thank to everyone for replying! I ended up solving the issue by installing SQLite/SQL Server Compact Toolbox in Visual studio